# what is the different between X.509 certificate and 2-way SSL? or both are same?

Tags: tls, authentication, openssl, x.509, sslstrip

Can anyone clarify what is the difference between an X509 certificate and two-way SSL? or both are same?

Comment: Does this help you http://security.stackexchange.com/a/1441/10439 ?

Answer (score 0):

X509 is the type for SSL certificates, these can differ in the purpose they have. When using a SSL connection with a server you use a X509 certificate with the purpose of server authentication: `TLS Web Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)` when using it for client authentication (2 way SSL) you need a certificate with `TLS Web Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)`.

Most certificates you buy already have these 2 purposes, you can check this by looking at the extended key usage in the certificate details.

Answer (score 0):

An X.509 certificate is a format for sharing a public key along with the name of the entity that holds that public/private key pair and optional extensions such as usage.  It is usually signed by a certificate authority in order that it is trusted.

A X.509 certificate is used in many applications that rely on public/private keys for authentication and/or encryption.  One example as you point out is SSL/TLS.  They are also used in other applications such as secure and/or signed emails using S/MIME. IPSec also uses them. Certificate Authorities use them to derive trust.

So, to answer your question: X.509 is a format for handling certificates. SSL is a protocol that, along with other protocols, uses those certificates.